# Find usages of method group syntax in solution

Tags: c#, resharper

I am trying to identify usages of the "method group" syntax in my solution. The reason is that Resharper tries to help with the ConvertClosureToMethodGroup code inspection. The problem is, that the "optimized" code does not compile to the same IL code, which means that it breaks in my specific scenario. The below scenario does not break, but it illustrates what I am trying to find:

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new string[]{"foo"};

    //This works
    var bar = arr.Select(s=>MyMethod(s));

    //Resharper suggests the below, which is different
    //var bar = arr.Select(MyMethod);

}

string MyMethod(string s)
{
    return "bar";
}
```

So: Is there a way, that I can identify all the places in my code, where any method is being passed as a method group?

I can disable the refactoring suggestion to prevent future usages of this, but how can I identify the places where this already happened?

EDIT 1: Example where this refactoring breaks runtime

```
void Main()
{
    MyClass obj = null;

    //This works
    var lazy = new Lazy<bool>(()=> obj.MyMethod());

    //This will break at runtime when obj is null
    //var lazy = new Lazy<bool>(obj.MyMethod);

}

class MyClass
{
    public bool MyMethod()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, do you have any simple examples which 'break' between the two uses?

Comment: Added an example where it will break at runtime.